# How to escape this | special character in Python. Is a common separator in maya for same names on different groups

Tags: regex, character

How to identify this `|` special character in Regular expressions Python?

I need to separate this list to groups:

```
['group1|group2|object_04']
```

to:

```
[|, group1, group2, object, _, 04]
```

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your question [How to detect `|` with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216305/how-to-detect-this-symbol-with-python), I assume you want to separate your list into groups.

**Example**:

```
>>> import re
>>> lst = ['group1|group2|object_04']
>>> for x in lst:
...     parts = re.findall(r'[a-z0-9]+|[|_]', x)
...     print parts

['group1', '|', 'group2', '|', 'object', '_', '04']
```

Comment: Hi! I've found this answer very useful and my apologise about double post, the system crash and had to repeat it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just I'm wondering about the possibility of find out a way to deliver a variable like pattern on lst = variable

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Will the pipe character ever be escaped or will it only appear as a separator? If it only appears as a separator, then you could just do some basic string manipulation below:

```
final_list = []

x = 'group1|group2|object_04'
split_list = x.split('|')

for item in split_list:
  if '_' in item:
    final_list.extend(item.split('_'))
    final_list.append('_')
  else:
    final_list.append(item)
```

Comment: Why we need this `final_list.extend(item.split('_'))`?

Comment: He wanted object and 04 to be separate items in the resulting list set, so I split on the underscore also.